# Google maps - InfoWindow Height auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is my code I'm trying to set the height to auto to infowindow on marker based on content. Is there a way I can achive it without hack ?

```js
function initialize() {

//replace this variable with the json you generate in the google maps api wizard tool
//Styles Start
 var styles = [ { "featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#444444" } ] }, { "featureType": "landscape", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "color": "#f2f2f2" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "saturation": "-100" }, { "lightness": "57" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [ { "lightness": "1" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "saturation": -100 }, { "lightness": 45 } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "simplified" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station.bus", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station.bus", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "saturation": "0" }, { "lightness": "0" }, { "gamma": "1.00" }, { "weight": "1" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station.bus", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "saturation": "-100" }, { "weight": "1" }, { "lightness": "0" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station.rail", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station.rail", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "gamma": "1" }, { "lightness": "40" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station.rail", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "saturation": "-100" }, { "lightness": "30" } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "color": "#d2d2d2" }, { "visibility": "on" } ] } ];

//Styles End
   //Create a styled map using the above styles
   var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,{name: "Styled Map"}); 

   var mapProp = { 
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(52.922592, -1.474605),//set the centre of the map. In my case it is the same as the position of the map pin.
      zoom:14,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

   var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

   //Set the map to use the styled map
   map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
   map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
   var contentString = '<div id="google-popup">'+
            '<p>Styled egege eg hrh rh jhh 454h 54h54h54dwwfwf fwwfe gh34h54 j54 j56j65jtj 45jh54j45j 54jh 5j54j54j54j5  eg egeg 54j54j45j54<a target="_blank" href="#">codeshare.co.uk</a><br /></p>'+
            '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

   //Create a marker pin to add to the map
   var marker;
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.922592, -1.474605),//set the position of the pin
      map: map,
      title: "Derby",
      icon: "http://www.codeshare.co.uk/images/blue-pin.png", //if you comment this out or delete it you will get the default pin icon.
      animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
   });


    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
  #googleMap { width: 100%; height: 400px; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
       
         /*style the box*/  
         .gm-style .gm-style-iw {
            background-color: #687e9c !important;
            top: 0 !important;
            left: 0 !important;
            width: 100% !important;
            height:100% !important;
            display: block !important;
         }    
     
         /*style the p tag*/
         .gm-style .gm-style-iw #google-popup p{
            padding: 10px;
         }
         
     
        /*style the arrow*/
        .gm-style div div div div div div div div {
            background-color: #687e9c !important;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            top: 0;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        
        /*style the link*/
        .gm-style div div div div div div div div a {
            color: #687e9c;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

```html
<div id="googleMap"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.20&sensor=false"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the height `height:100% !important;` from the below class so that it will work. Height of popup will increase based on the content of popup.

```
     .gm-style .gm-style-iw {
        background-color: #687e9c !important;
        top: 0 !important;
        left: 0 !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        # Comment or remove the below height
        #height:100% !important;
        display: block !important;
     }
```

```js
function initialize() {

    //replace this variable with the json you generate in the google maps api wizard tool
    //Styles Start
     var styles = [ { "featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#444444" } ] }, { "featureType": "landscape", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "color": "#f2f2f2" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "saturation": "-100" }, { "lightness": "57" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [ { "lightness": "1" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "saturation": -100 }, { "lightness": 45 } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "simplified" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station.bus", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station.bus", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "saturation": "0" }, { "lightness": "0" }, { "gamma": "1.00" }, { "weight": "1" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station.bus", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "saturation": "-100" }, { "weight": "1" }, { "lightness": "0" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station.rail", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station.rail", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "gamma": "1" }, { "lightness": "40" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station.rail", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "saturation": "-100" }, { "lightness": "30" } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [ { "color": "#d2d2d2" }, { "visibility": "on" } ] } ];

    //Styles End
       //Create a styled map using the above styles
       var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,{name: "Styled Map"}); 

       var mapProp = { 
          center:new google.maps.LatLng(52.922592, -1.474605),//set the centre of the map. In my case it is the same as the position of the map pin.
          zoom:14,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };

       var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

       //Set the map to use the styled map
       map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
       map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
       var contentString = '<div id="google-popup">'+
                '<p>Styled egege eg hrsd csc scs cscscdsc sc s cscscscsd c cs cscs cscs c scsdddddddsdc sd csdfr ferfwef efewf  hkikuilllih rh jhh 454h 54h54h54dwwfwf fwwfe gh34h54 j54 j56j65jtj 45jh54j45j 54jh 5j54j54j54j5  eg egeg 54j54j45j54<a target="_blank" href="#">codeshare.co.uk</a><br /></p>'+
                '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

       //Create a marker pin to add to the map
       var marker;
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.922592, -1.474605),//set the position of the pin
          map: map,
          title: "Derby",
          icon: "http://www.codeshare.co.uk/images/blue-pin.png", //if you comment this out or delete it you will get the default pin icon.
          animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
       });


        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      


    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
      #googleMap { width: 100%; height: 400px; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
           
             /*style the box*/  
             .gm-style .gm-style-iw {
                background-color: #687e9c !important;
                top: 0 !important;
                left: 0 !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                #height:auto !important;
                display: block !important;
             }    
         
             /*style the p tag*/
             .gm-style .gm-style-iw #google-popup p{
                padding: 10px;
             }
             
         
            /*style the arrow*/
            .gm-style div div div div div div div div {
                background-color: #687e9c !important;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                top: 0;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            
            /*style the link*/
            .gm-style div div div div div div div div a {
                color: #687e9c;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.20&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

Comment: #height:auto !important; did the trick